# Why does portrait page changes to landscape page after inserting pdf using iText?

Tags: java, itext

Am using "itext-5.5.8", trying to insert (one) page of portrait pdf into a main pdf document, code works perfect but after inserting portrait pages automatically changes to landscape pages, don't know why?

**CODE:**

```
try {
        PdfReader firstPdf = new PdfReader(mainFileWithPath); //main doc
        PdfReader secondPdf =new PdfReader(addFileNameWithPath); // inserting pages

        PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(firstPdf, new FileOutputStream(outputPDFFile));

            int totalNumOfPagesToInsert = secondPdf.getNumberOfPages();
            int i =1;
            while (i<=totalNumOfPagesToInsert) {
                // Get a page(s) from secondPdf with the given pageNo
                PdfImportedPage page  = stamp.getImportedPage(secondPdf,i);

                // insert new page in to the newly created pdf at specified page number.
                stamp.insertPage(INSERT_AT_PAGE_NO + (i-1), secondPdf.getPageSize(i));

                // copy the content of the page copied from secondPdf.
                stamp.getUnderContent(INSERT_AT_PAGE_NO + (i-1)).addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                i++;
            }

            //close the new created pdf.
            stamp.close();
```

Please give me directions to fix this! Thanks

Comment: Maybe the original page has a rotation. You can check this by using `secondPdf.getPageRotation(i)`. Note that you're currently using `secondPdf.getPageSize(i)`. That may result in a different page size when compared to using `secondPdf.getPageSizeWithRotation(i)`. Also I wouldn't use `PdfStamper` to insert pages (you'll lose all the interactivity that might present in the inserted pages). Is there a specific reason why you're not using `PdfCopy`?

Comment: Thanks Author @Bruno Lowagie, secondPdf.getPageRotation(1) gives me 270, There is no reason to using 'PdfCopy', I use it... which resolves my issue hopefully.

Comment: Aha, the fact that `getPageRotation(1)` gives you 270 explains the difference between the original and your copy. When adding the page to `PdfStamper`, you didn't take into account that rotation.

Answer (score 1):

As Author @Bruno Lowagie mentioned that "*didn't take into account that rotation*"

Have fixed the issue like ... **Code Below** ...

```
try {

            PdfReader firstPdf = new PdfReader(mainFileWithPath);
            PdfReader secondPdf =new PdfReader(addFileNameWithPath);

            // create new pdf with the content from firstPdf
            PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(firstPdf, new FileOutputStream(outputPDFFile));
            stamp.setRotateContents(false);

            int totalNumOfPagesToInsert = secondPdf.getNumberOfPages();
            int i =1;
            while (i<=totalNumOfPagesToInsert) {
                // Get a single page from secondPdf with the given pageNo
                PdfImportedPage page  = stamp.getImportedPage(secondPdf,i); //Actual working code

                // insert new page in to the newly created pdf at specified page number.
                // choose page size bas
                stamp.insertPage(INSERT_AT_PAGE_NO + (i-1), secondPdf.getPageSizeWithRotation(i)); //Actual working code

                // copy the content of the page copied from secondPdf.
                stamp.getUnderContent(INSERT_AT_PAGE_NO + (i-1)).addTemplate(page, 0, 0); //Actual working code

                i++;
            }

            //close the new created pdf.
            stamp.close();
```